# Is the topology on compact connected Lie groups metrizable?

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, topological-groups, locally-compact-groups, metrizability

The question is in the title, really.

Suppose $G$ is a compact connected Lie group. Is there a metric on $G$ which induces the underlying topology? (so in particular $G$ is compact and connected wrt this metric).

I am not really from this area (my differential geometry is slack, to say the least). I am purely interested in the existence of such a metric.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a general topology viewpoint: a Lie group $G$ is locally Euclidean, so locally metrisable. Also $G$ is compact and hence paracompact. It's $T_1$ (from locally Euclidean) and as a topological group this means $G$ is Tychonoff, Hausdorff etc.

So several metrisation theorems do apply: Bing-Nagata-Smirnov, Smirnov, Urysohn even. I don't think connectedness is necessary : $G$ can have only finitely many components (being compact and locally connected) and a finite sum of metrisable spaces still is metrisable. So $G$ is certainly metrisable.

Comment: Thanks. I think connectedness is not required for the existence of a metric, but is required to say that this metric is left invariant (i.e. $d(gx,gy)=d(x,y)$. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_group and https://mathoverflow.net/questions/262298/reference-request-any-connected-lie-group-has-a-countable-base-for-its-topology. Feel free to chime in with words of (dis)agreement :)

Comment: @Artur the Wikipedia page states that any locally compact topological group that is metrisable has a left invariant metric. No connectedness needed there.

Comment: It says, and I quote, "Every locally compact group which is second-countable is metrizable as a topological group (i.e. can be given a left-invariant metric compatible with the topology) ". Now this confuses me further - is left invariance part of the definition of being metrizable as a topological group? Or perhaps this follows from something which I am failing to see?

Comment: @Artur your $G$ must be second countable, connected or not.

Comment: AHH sorry I am silly. Connectedness is not required, but is just an example of... Thanks for that!

Comment: @Artur the left invariant metric is a consequence of a theorem.

Comment: Do you have a reference or name of said theorem?

Comment: @Artur it’s Birkhoff’s theorem. Any good topological group text book should cover it.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is yes, I believe. The metric that you would be looking for would be the one induced by the Killing form. There is a really good discussion on the construction of the Killing form and its properties here:

http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/ph251/KillingForm.pdf

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, but is this metric $G$-invariant? i.e., $d(gx,gy)=d(x,y)$ for $x,y,g\in G$?

Comment: Since you are using a compact Lie group, yes it is. In general, the Killing form forms the unique G-invariant Riemannian metric on symmetric spaces G/K for K a maximal compact subgroup.

Comment: No, if $G$ is not semisimple, then the Killing form has a nontrivial kernel (if $G$ is abelian, the Killing form is zero). Still $G$ admits a bi-invariant Riemannian metric. If $G$ is semisimple then the Killing form indeed yields a bi-invariant metric, and the other ones are obtained by rescaling on each simple factor.